# tasks being created with same task_id in queue

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using Django-celery and Redis backend to push the tasks in celery queue. I am pushing tasks with same custom task_id in the queue. The documentation says that task_id is UUID which should be unique. But I am able to add more than one task with the same task_id in the queue. It is expected that it should raise an exception if a task with the same task_id is already there in the queue.

```
@task
def register_task(a, b):
    print a + b

@task
def deregister_task(a, b, c):
    print a + b + c

taskid=str(UUID(md5('test').hexdigest()))
register_task.apply_async(args=('hello', 'world'), task_id=taskid, countdown=60)
deregister_task.apply_async(args=('sample', 'hello', 'world'), task_id=taskid, countdown=60)
i = inspect()
i.scheduled()

{u'celery@Suyashs-MacBook-Pro.local': [{u'eta': u'2017-06-05T17:15:33.947002',
   u'priority': 6,
   u'request': {u'acknowledged': False,
    u'args': u"('sample', 'hello', 'world')",
    u'delivery_info': {u'exchange': u'celery',
     u'priority': 0,
     u'redelivered': None,
     u'routing_key': u'celery'},
    u'hostname': u'celery@Suyashs-MacBook-Pro.local',
    u'id': u'098f6bcd-4621-d373-cade-4e832627b4f6',
    u'kwargs': u'{}',
    u'name': u'flight.tasks.deregister_task',
    u'time_start': None,
    u'worker_pid': None}},
  {u'eta': u'2017-06-05T17:15:44.234537',
   u'priority': 6,
   u'request': {u'acknowledged': False,
    u'args': u"('hello', 'world')",
    u'delivery_info': {u'exchange': u'celery',
     u'priority': 0,
     u'redelivered': None,
     u'routing_key': u'celery'},
    u'hostname': u'celery@Suyashs-MacBook-Pro.local',
    u'id': u'098f6bcd-4621-d373-cade-4e832627b4f6',
    u'kwargs': u'{}',
    u'name': u'flight.tasks.register_task',
    u'time_start': None,
    u'worker_pid': None}}]}
```

Comment: Based on the code snippet I can speculate either of two things. First, a task is already being picked up from the queue before the new one gets added. To test this you can add sleep in your task code and queue multiple tasks. Second, if celery not raising exception then, you'll lose the handle to all previous task. Celery creates an independent queue with `<worker>.<taskid>` for communication, which means client cannot differntiate between tasks.

Comment: I've added countdown=60, that means task will be added to the queue but it won't be executed immediately. i.scheduled() shows both the tasks that mean both tasks are there in the queue.